# AWS Code Whisperer and GitHub CoPilot Capabilities

Tags: github-copilot, amazon-codewhisperer

How can AWS CodeWhisperer be leverage in a migration from PySpark to SQL in DBT? How can GitHub CoPilot be used in this type of migration?

I cannot find information on this and my skills tend to lean more data visualization.